# MS Access SQL Reorder Dates for Trailing 12 Months

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to format a query correctly to make Access 365 charting work properly (I know, I know) for a trailing 12 month graph. I.E. if I run this query in June, I want June to be the last data point (Month 12) and proceed backwards in order to the previous July (Month 1). I'm getting stuck on how to build this logic into the query as the order is constant but the relative number changes. I have:

```
FROM (
SELECT "Jan" as Mo,Month(DateAdd("m",1,Date())) AS MoN, SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 1,1,0)) AS             SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 1,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Feb", Month(DateAdd("m",2,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 2,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 2,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Mar", Month(DateAdd("m",3,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 3,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 3,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Apr", Month(DateAdd("m",4,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 4,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 4,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "May", Month(DateAdd("m",5,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 5,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 5,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Jun", Month(DateAdd("m",6,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 6,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 6,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Jul", Month(DateAdd("m",7,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 7,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 7,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Aug", Month(DateAdd("m",8,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 8,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 8,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Sep", Month(DateAdd("m",9,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 9,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 9,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Oct", Month(DateAdd("m",10,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 10,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 10,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Nov", Month(DateAdd("m",11,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 11,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 11,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
UNION SELECT "Dec", Month(DateAdd("m",12,Date())), SUM(IIF(MonthNumOpen = 12,1,0)) AS SalesOpened,SUM(IIF(MonthNumClose = 12,1,0)) AS Sales, Month(Date()) as Today1, Sales - SalesOpened  as SalesDelta FROM Trailing12MonthData_Trial1
ORDER BY MoN
)  AS subquery
ORDER BY IIF(Month(Date()) = 11, Mo ="Jan", IIF(Month(Date()) = 10, Mo="Feb",IIF(Month(Date()) = 9, Mo="Mar",IIF(Month(Date()) = 8, Mo="Apr",IIF(Month(Date()) = 7, Mo="May",IIF(Month(Date()) = 6, Mo="Jun",IIF(Month(Date()) = 5, Mo="Jul",IIF(Month(Date()) = 4, Mo="Aug",IIF(Month(Date()) = 3, Mo="Sep",IIF(Month(Date()) = 2, Mo="Oct",IIF(Month(Date()) = 1, Mo="Nov", Mo="Dec"))))))))))), MoN;
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text table. What style chart?

Answer (score 0):

Use *modulus* to calculate the period for each month. Here *June* is the current month:

```vb
For M = 1 to 12 : ? "Period: " & M, "Month: " & (Month(Date) - 1 + M) Mod 12 + 1 : Next
Period: 1     Month: 7
Period: 2     Month: 8
Period: 3     Month: 9
Period: 4     Month: 10
Period: 5     Month: 11
Period: 6     Month: 12
Period: 7     Month: 1
Period: 8     Month: 2
Period: 9     Month: 3
Period: 10    Month: 4
Period: 11    Month: 5
Period: 12    Month: 6
```

Then you probably can reduce this query dramatically.